# Netbeans, can't save edits I make on my project's files

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, pom.xml

I got an existing Java project, with a `pom.xml` file, the project is using Maven. I can successfully open it with netbean, compile and run it. However when I want to make edits to the files, I can't save them (Save option is greyed in the File menu).

I can edit the files with another editor and then use netbeans to compile them but it's a pain.

Any idea about this behaviour ? I couldn't find similar issues on the web…

I'm using :

- Netbeans 7.0.1
- Xubuntu 12.04

Comment: Can you write the file outside of the IDE (e.g. what happens if you try `touch pom.xml`)?

Comment: try importing that project  in another workspace as existing maven project

Comment: @UwePlonus Yes that's what I actually do, using vim for editing and netbeans for compilation

Comment: With which user are you starting Netbeans and to whom do the files belong to? Sounds like Netbeans is not having the permission to write those files.

Comment: the files belong to me, and I start netbeans when I'm logged with the graphical laucher… Note, I also tried to launch netbeans as root, same issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when i added a part of code to persistence.xml file. I removed this code and the error was fixed. Try to remove something that you added befor and that caused this problem.